# Render svelte component slot from a variable

Tags: svelte

Instead of using regular approach:

```
<slot name="myslot" />
```

I would like to render slots from `$$props.$$slots` directly.

So far, I couldn't achieve that with any of those methods:

```
{$$props.$$slots.myslot} // that gives a string representation of the code
{$$props.$$slots.myslot[0]} // same
<svelte:component this={$$props.$$slots.myslot} /> // error
<svelte:component this={$$props.$$slots.myslot[0]} /> // error
<svelte:fragment>{$$props.$$slots.myslot}</svelte:fragment> // error
```

Is there a way to render a component or slot from a variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is not supported.

`$$props.$$slots` is internal and not meant to be used outside the Svelte runtime code. You could analyze the compiled output and use the functions from `svelte/internal` but it can (and probably *will*) break at any point.

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer. I am unhappy about it, but still thank you :)

Looks like the only way is to always create a real component and pass the import as a prop

Comment: Maybe you do not need to do either. You only asked about what you think you need to do, not what you are actually trying to achieve as an end goal. Maybe there is a way to just use `<slot>`, maybe not.

Answer (score 0):

This should be possible with regular variables or props.

[This REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/91e79b8c4ddc4691bc714983eec8c47c?version=4.2.0) shows it live.

#### Code

A renderer component will render whatever control is given to it through its `component` prop:

```html
<script>
    export let component;
    export let componentProps = undefined;
</script>

{#if component}
  <svelte:component this={component} {...componentProps} />
{/if}
```

The interested party, in the example `App.svelte`, lays a renderer out and provides a mechanism to select the component of choice.  The example uses a SELECT input element:

```html
<script lang="ts">
    import C1 from './C1.svelte';
    import C2 from './C2.svelte';
    import Renderer from './Renderer.svelte';

    let choice = C1;
    let msg = 'Hi!';
    const choices = [
        C1,
        C2
    ];
</script>

<input type="text" bind:value={msg} />
<select bind:value={choice}>
    {#each choices as c, i (i)}
        <option value={c}>{i}</option>
    {/each}
</select>
<Renderer component={choice} componentProps={{ msg }} />

<style>
    div.container {
        display: flex;
    }
    div.overflow-hidden {
        overflow: hidden;
    }
</style>
```

> Notice the imports of the components.  Just as per usual.  However, they are used in the script section instead of laying them out in markup inside a slot.

This would be C1:

```html
<script>
    export let msg;
</script>

<div>
    I'm C1.
    <blockquote>{msg}</blockquote>
</div>
```

The `C2` component is basically identical.

#### Summary

The trick is in `Renderer`:  Set this with the variable/prop that has the Svelte component struct, and then spread the properties.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but I specifically asked about slots, cause then I can easier visualize my layout in code instead of having everything hidden behind a component and passed as a prop